# NaN value appears after concat two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I tried to create a new dataframe by one-hot encoding some of the columns of a dataframe and standardising them together with some other columns, without any NaN data up to this point. I then joined it to a dataframe with an equal number of rows, only one column and no one-hot encoding and standardisation. The new dataframe resulting from the concatenation has a lot of NaN data in it, and I don't understand why.

Here is the code

The shape of the dataframe after one-hot encoding is (29141, 23), the shape of the dataframe after standardisation is (29141, 22), and the shape of the dataframe to be concatenated with it is (29141, 1)

```
#one-hot encode the 'wd' colum
def add_wd_onehot(df):
    enc_wd = pd.get_dummies(df.wd,prefix='wd')
    df = df.drop(['wd'],axis=1)
    df = df.join(enc_wd)
    return df

#Standardise all columns except the first one
def standardise(df):
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    sta_df = DataFrame(df.iloc[:,1:])
    df = DataFrame(df.iloc[:,0])
    sta_df = DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(sta_df))
    df = df.join(sta_df)
    return df

train_df_preprocessed = standardise(add_wd_onehot(train_df))
train_df_preprocessed
```

I don't think there should be NaN values after two dataframes are concatenated because there were no NaN values before the concatenation and they have the same number of rows,  but the fact is that there is a lot of NaN data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyLbg.png)

Comment: I seem to have found the cause of the error. The NaN value appears because I concatenated the two as a dataframe, if I concatenated them as a ndarray and then transformed the result into a dataframe the error would not occur.